# C# reflection to check method body of assignment to fields

Tags: c#, reflection, compilation, lint

For the class below :

```
class A
{
    private List<int> intList;
    private List<bool> boolList;

    public InitializeClass()
    {
        intList = new List<int>();
    }

}
```

I want to use reflection to write a linter/post compiler of sorts, to check if a certain method really have any assignment to the class' fields or not. The purpose is to automatically check my own errors. The class cannot use constructor, so I need to call `InitializeClass()` manually.

I have `MethodInfo method` and all fields of class `FieldInfo[] fields` that I wanted to check already but have no idea how to go from here. From the example above, it should be able to detect that I haven't assign anything to `boolList` in the method body.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to do this from the compiled code? Using the Roslyn API would be a much simpler way of analyzing the code.

Comment: Yes, this is actually Unity3D plugin. Unity can run any C# static method after compilation in the program itself, so I wanted to run the checker there to analyze all scripts that I am using in the current scene.

Comment: But do you not actually know the code you want to check at build time? How much effort are you willing to go to support doing this at execution time vs at build time? I suspect that finding an IL-parsing library that works on Unity is going to be a tall order.

Comment: I marked the class that I wanted to check with attribute and with combinations of Unity command it can scan for all said class in the scene. Currently I already have access to `MethodInfo` of the method I want to check. I guess I have to use `MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray` method and split each line based on "=" character and check the left side for matching name I suppose?

Comment: No, because you're getting the method body *as IL*. There's no concept of lines, and `=` characters... it's the CLR version of machine code, not source code. I still think you should just find all the classes you want to check for this at build time, and do the checking then.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I will have to read back to the code file itself and find the method that have matching name to `MethodInfo.Name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reading the code file directly using regular expression.
The file has some constraint, that is it can contains unlimited methods but each method cannot contain any brackets. (No if, etc.)

Then I use `"({)(.*)(})"` and choose the 2nd group to eliminate class's bracket, then from that I used `"{(.*?)}"` and iterate through matches for each method's body. (I don't care about method's name actually, I want to check the entire file) After that I read the method's content line by line and split things with characters like '=' or '.'